# asking for a XPath query string

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

How to parse the "File" node under "File and Folder Items" using Xpath

```
<TreeView>
- <Node>
  Catalog 
- <Node>
  Device Items 
  <Node>A1</Node> 
  <Node>A2</Node> 
  </Node>
- <Node>
  File and Folder Items 
  <Node>File</Node>              <-- here!!!
  <Node>Folder</Node> 
  </Node>
  <Node>CCC</Node> 
  </Node>
  </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Node[normalize-space(text())="File and Folder Items"]/Node[1]
```

See [example](http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx?xpath=%2F%2FNode%5bnormalize-space%28text%28%29%29%3D%22File+and+Folder+Items%22%5d%2FNode%5b1%5d&xml=%3CTreeView%3E%0D%0A%3CNode%3E%0D%0A++Catalog+%0D%0A+%3CNode%3E%0D%0A++Device+Items+%0D%0A++%3CNode%3EA1%3C%2FNode%3E+%0D%0A++%3CNode%3EA2%3C%2FNode%3E+%0D%0A++%3C%2FNode%3E%0D%0A+%3CNode%3E%0D%0A++File+and+Folder+Items+%0D%0A++%3CNode%3EFile%3C%2FNode%3E++++++++++%0D%0A++%3CNode%3EFolder%3C%2FNode%3E+%0D%0A++%3C%2FNode%3E%0D%0A++%3CNode%3ECCC%3C%2FNode%3E+%0D%0A++%3C%2FNode%3E%0D%0A++%3C%2FTreeView%3E).

Comment: Artefacto's solution is working for me.

i think that safer is `//Node[normalize-space(text()[1])="File and Folder Items"]/Node[text()="File"]`